# Date not converting correctly in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, date, cultureinfo

It seems like I keep having problems with dates.  I am using the following code:

```
        Dim LocalDateCultureProvider As New CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString)
         Dim CurrentDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        ExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", LocalDateCultureProvider)
        If DateTime.Compare(ExpiryDate, CurrentDate) < 0 Then

MsgBox("This file has expired.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Here I am reading strDate as a string and for one example, the value of this is "29/09/2012"  However, in the ExpiryDate line it converts to #09/29/2012# so that in the comparison with today's date which is stored (correctly in my opinion) in CurrentDate as #10/6/2012# I get the If condition to be true (wrongly).

BTW, I also tried 
          Dim LocalDateCultureProvider As New CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.ToString)

just to see if that was causing the problem.  I am trying to build something that will work in all Cultures.  No matter what the local settings are, I want to test for expiration by comparing the current system date with an expiration date which I receive as a string.  Please tell me how to go about this so I can get consistent results.

TIA,
Chiwda

Answer (score 1):

No, you parse the CurrentDate incorrectly.  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture expects the month before the day but you formatted it with the day first.  You are writing unnecessary code, simply fix with:

```
    If DateTime.Compare(ExpiryDate, DateTime.Now) < 0 Then
```

Comment: But isn't that true in the US only?  For example in other countries, the system date is in dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: You were using *InvariantCulture*, it is the same everywhere.  It just doesn't make sense to convert a DateTime to a string and then back again to a DateTime.  Getting it wrong is the outcome.

Comment: VB.Net won't let you do `If (ExpiryDate < DateTime.Now) then` ?

Comment: Oh no, it works, but right now I do not have a machine (will Monday morning) which has a non-US date format.  I suspect I will have problems because I have in the past with date conversions.

Comment: As I suspected, there is a problem with the code on a machine whose system date is in the dd/MM/yyyy format.  See here http://www.l3media.tv/error.png

Comment: If you speak English in India then you're supposed to write your dates as "29-09-2012".  Dashes, not slashes.  Why you keep putting dates in strings is very hard to guess.

Comment: "Why you keep putting dates in strings is very hard to guess" - Because I am reading the date from a text file.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand why dates have to be with - not /

Comment: Because you are not using InvariantCulture to convert the string, you are using the local culture.  en-IN dates should use a dash, not a slash.

Comment: So what should I change in the above code so that it works in any culture?  Is there some "best practices" document that I can read?  Appreciate your help.